# Awesome Support Custom Field for show Woocommerce orders

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

im new woocommerce plugin developer
i want add custom field (select type) to Awesome Support plugin to show woocommerce order of users.

its my plugin main code

```
<?php
/**
 * @package   Awesome Support Woocommerce
 * @author    Ehsan Yarmohammadi <e.yarmohammadi@gmail.com>
 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name:       Awesome Support Woocommerce
 * Description:       Adds custom fields to the Awesome Support ticket submission form.
 * Version:           0.1.0
 * Text Domain:       wpas
 * License:           GPL-2.0+
 * Domain Path:       /languages
 */
// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Instantiate the plugin
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
* Register the activation hook
*/

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'WPASS_Woocommerce_Loader', 'activate' ) );
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'WPASS_Woocommerce_Loader', 'get_instance' ) );

/**
* Instantiate the addon.
*
* This method runs a few checks to make sure that the addon
* can indeed be used in the current context, after what it
* registers the addon to the core plugin for it to be loaded
* when the entire core is ready.
*
* @since  0.1.0
* @return void
*/
class WPASS_Woocommerce_Loader {
    /**
    * ID of the item.
    *
    * The item ID must match teh post ID on the e-commerce site.
    * Using the item ID instead of its name has the huge advantage of
    * allowing changes in the item name.
    *
    * If the ID is not set the class will fall back on the plugin name instead.
    *
    * @since 0.1.3
    * @var int
    */
    protected $item_id = 675765;

    /**
    * Required version of the core.
    *
    * The minimum version of the core that's required
    * to properly run this addon. If the minimum version
    * requirement isn't met an error message is displayed
    * and the addon isn't registered.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @var    string
    */
    protected $version_required = '4.0.0';

    /**
    * Required version of PHP.
    *
    * Follow WordPress latest requirements and require
    * PHP version 5.4 at least.
    * 
    * @var string
    */
    protected $php_version_required = '5.6';

    /**
    * Plugin slug.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @var    string
    */
    protected $slug = 'wpass_woocommerce';

    /**
    * Instance of this loader class.
    *
    * @since    0.1.0
    * @var      object
    */
    protected static $instance = null;

    /**
    * Instance of the addon itself.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @var    object
    */
    public $addon = null;

    /**
    * Possible error message.
    * 
    * @var null|WP_Error
    */
    protected $error = null;

    /**
    * WPASS_Woocommerce_Loader constructor
    */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->declare_constants();
        $this->init();
    }

    /**
    * Return an instance of this class.
    *
    * @since     3.0.0
    * @return    object    A single instance of this class.
    */
    public static function get_instance() {
    // If the single instance hasn't been set, set it now.
    if ( null == self::$instance ) {
        self::$instance = new self;
    }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
    * Return an instance of the addon.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @return object
    */
    public function scope() {
        return $this->addon;
    }

    /**
    * Declare addon constants
    *
    * @since 1.0.0
    * @return void
    */
    public function declare_constants() {
        define( 'WPASS_WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION', '1.0.3' );
        define( 'WPASS_WOOCOMMERCE_URL', trailingslashit( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ) );
        define( 'WPASS_WOOCOMMERCE_PATH', trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) );
        define( 'WPASS_WOOCOMMERCE_ROOT', trailingslashit( dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) );
        define( 'PLUGINS_PATH'      , trailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) ) );
    }

    /**
    * Activate the plugin.
    *
    * The activation method just checks if the main plugin
    * Awesome Support is installed (active or inactive) on the site.
    * If not, the addon installation is aborted and an error message is displayed.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @return void
    */
    public static function activate() {
        if ( ! class_exists( 'Awesome_Support' ) ) {
            deactivate_plugins( basename( __FILE__ ) );
            wp_die(
                sprintf( __( 'You need Awesome Support to activate this addon. Please <a href="%s" target="_blank">install Awesome Support</a> before continuing.', 'wpass_woocommerce' ), esc_url( 'https://getawesomesupport.com/?utm_source=internal&utm_medium=addon_loader&utm_campaign=Addons' ) )
            );
        }

        if ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
            deactivate_plugins( basename( __FILE__ ) );
            wp_die(
                sprintf( __( 'You need WooCommerce to activate this addon. Please <a href="%s" target="_blank">install WooCommerce</a> before continuing.', 'wpass_woocommerce' ), esc_url( 'https://getawesomesupport.com/?utm_source=internal&utm_medium=addon_loader&utm_campaign=Addons' ) )
            );
        }
    }

    /**
    * Initialize the addon.
    *
    * This method is the one running the checks and
    * registering the addon to the core.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @return boolean Whether or not the addon was registered
    */
    public function init() {
        $plugin_name = $this->plugin_data( 'Name' );  

        if ( ! $this->is_core_active() ) {
            $this->add_error( sprintf( __( '%s requires Awesome Support to be active. Please activate the core plugin first.', 'wpass_woocommerce' ), $plugin_name ) );
        }

        if ( ! $this->is_Woocommerce_active() ) {
            $this->add_error( sprintf( __( '%s requires Woocommerce to be active. Please activate the Woocommerce first.', 'wpass_woocommerce' ), $plugin_name ) );
        }

        if ( ! $this->is_php_version_enough() ) {
            $this->add_error( sprintf( __( 'Unfortunately, %s can not run on PHP versions older than %s. Read more information about <a href="%s" target="_blank">how you can update</a>.', 'wpass_woocommerce' ), $plugin_name, $this->php_version_required, esc_url( 'http://www.wpupdatephp.com/update/' ) ) );
        }

        if ( ! $this->is_version_compatible() ) {
            $this->add_error( sprintf( __( '%s requires Awesome Support version %s or greater. Please update the core plugin first.', 'wpass_woocommerce' ), $plugin_name, $this->version_required ) );
        }

        // Load the plugin translation.
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'load_plugin_textdomain' ), 15 );

        if ( is_a( $this->error, 'WP_Error' ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'display_error' ), 10, 0 );
            add_action( 'admin_init',    array( $this, 'deactivate' ),    10, 0 );
            return false;
        }

        /**
        * Add the addon license field
        */
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            // Add the license admin notice
            //$this->add_license_notice();
            add_filter( 'wpas_addons_licenses', array( $this, 'addon_license' ),       10, 1 );
            add_filter( 'plugin_row_meta',      array( $this, 'license_notice_meta' ), 10, 4 );
        }

        /**
        * Register the addon
        */
        wpas_register_addon( $this->slug, array( $this, 'load' ) );

        return true;

    }

    /**
    * Get the plugin data.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @param  string $data Plugin data to retrieve
    * @return string       Data value
    */
    protected function plugin_data( $data ) {

        if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugin_data' ) ) {

            $site_url = get_site_url() . '/';

            if ( defined( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN' ) && FORCE_SSL_ADMIN && 'http://' === substr( $site_url, 0, 7 ) ) {
                $site_url = str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $site_url );
            }

            $admin_path = str_replace( $site_url, ABSPATH, get_admin_url() );

            require_once( $admin_path . 'includes/plugin.php' );

        }

        $plugin = get_plugin_data( __FILE__, false, false );

        if ( array_key_exists( $data, $plugin ) ){
            return $plugin[$data];
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    /**
    * Check if core is active.
    *
    * Checks if the core plugin is listed in the active
    * plugins in the WordPress database.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @return boolean Whether or not the core is active
    */
    protected function is_core_active() {
        if ( in_array( 'awesome-support/awesome-support.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Check if Woocomerce is active.
    *
    * Checks if the Woocomerce plugin is listed in the active
    * plugins in the WordPress database.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @return boolean Whether or not the Woocomerce is active
    */
    protected function is_Woocommerce_active() {
        if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
    * Check if the core version is compatible with this addon.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @return boolean
    */
    protected function is_version_compatible() {

        /**
        * Return true if the core is not active so that this message won't show.
        * We already have the error saying the plugin is disabled, no need to add this one.
        */
        if ( ! $this->is_core_active() ) {
            return true;
        }

        if ( empty( $this->version_required ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        if ( ! defined( 'WPAS_VERSION' ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( version_compare( WPAS_VERSION, $this->version_required, '<' ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    /**
    * Check if the version of PHP is compatible with this addon.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @return boolean
    */
    protected function is_php_version_enough() {

        /**
        * No version set, we assume everything is fine.
        */
        if ( empty( $this->php_version_required ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        if ( version_compare( phpversion(), $this->php_version_required, '<' ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    /**
    * Add error.
    *
    * Add a new error to the WP_Error object
    * and create the object if it doesn't exist yet.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @param string $message Error message to add
    * @return void
    */
    public function add_error( $message ) {

        if ( ! is_object( $this->error ) || ! is_a( $this->error, 'WP_Error' ) ) {
            $this->error = new WP_Error();
        }

        $this->error->add( 'addon_error', $message );

    }

    /**
    * Display error.
    *
    * Get all the error messages and display them
    * in the admin notices.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @return void
    */
    public function display_error() {

        if ( ! is_a( $this->error, 'WP_Error' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $message = $this->error->get_error_messages(); ?>
        <div class="error">
            <p>
                <?php
                if ( count( $message ) > 1 ) {
                    echo '<ul>';
                    foreach ( $message as $msg ) {
                        echo "<li>$msg</li>";
                    }
                    echo '</li>';
                } else {
                    echo $message[0];
                }
                ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    <?php
    }

    /**
    * Deactivate the addon.
    *
    * If the requirements aren't met we try to
    * deactivate the addon completely.
    * 
    * @return void
    */
    public function deactivate() {
        if ( function_exists( 'deactivate_plugins' ) ) {
            deactivate_plugins( basename( __FILE__ ) );
        }
    }

    /**
    * Add license option.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @param  array $licenses List of addons licenses
    * @return array           Updated list of licenses
    */
    public function addon_license( $licenses ) {
        $plugin_name = $this->plugin_data( 'Name' );
        $plugin_name = trim( str_replace( 'Awesome Support:', '', $plugin_name ) ); // Remove the Awesome Support prefix from the addon name
        $licenses[] = array(
            'name'      => $plugin_name,
            'id'        => "license_{$this->slug}",
            'type'      => 'edd-license',
            'default'   => '',
            'server'    => esc_url( 'https://getawesomesupport.com' ),
            'item_name' => $plugin_name,
            'item_id'   => $this->item_id,
            'file'      => __FILE__
        );
        return $licenses;
    }

    /**
    * Display notice if user didn't set his license code
    *
    * @since 0.1.4
    * @return void
    */
    public function add_license_notice() {

        /**
        * We only want to display the notice to the site admin.
        */
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $license = wpas_get_option( "license_{$this->slug}", '' );

        /**
        * Do not show the notice if the license key has already been entered.
        */
        if ( ! empty( $license ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $link = wpas_get_settings_page_url( 'licenses' );

        WPAS()->admin_notices->add_notice( 'error', "license_{$this->slug}", sprintf( __( 'Please <a href="%s">fill-in your product license</a> now. If you don\'t, your copy of Awesome Suppport: WooCommerce <strong>will never be updated</strong>.', 'wpass_woocommerce' ), $link ) );

    }

    /**
    * Add license warning in the plugin meta row
    *
    * @since 0.1.0
    *
    * @param array  $plugin_meta The current plugin meta row
    * @param string $plugin_file The plugin file path
    *
    * @return array Updated plugin meta
    */
    public function license_notice_meta( $plugin_meta, $plugin_file ) {

        $license   = wpas_get_option( "license_{$this->slug}", '' );

        if( ! empty( $license ) ) {
            return $plugin_meta;
        }

        $license_page = wpas_get_settings_page_url( 'licenses' );

        if ( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) === $plugin_file ) {
            $plugin_meta[] = '<strong>' . sprintf( __( 'You must fill-in your product license in order to get future plugin updates. <a href="%s">Click here to do it</a>.', 'wpass_woocommerce' ), $license_page ) . '</strong>';
        }

        return $plugin_meta;

    }

    /**
    * Load the addon.
    *
    * Include all necessary files and instantiate the addon.
    *
    * @since  0.1.0
    * @return void
    */
    public function load() {

        require_once PLUGINS_PATH . 'awesome-support/includes/custom-fields/class-custom-field.php';
        require_once PLUGINS_PATH . 'awesome-support/includes/custom-fields/class-custom-fields.php';

        require_once WPASS_WOOCOMMERCE_PATH . 'includes/woocommerce/woocommerce.php';

        add_action( 'wpas_submission_form_inside_top', 'wc_get_customer_orders' );

        wc_get_customer_orders();

        //add_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', 'wc_get_customer_orders' ); 


        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'admin_enqueue_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'tf_save_admin_wpas', array( $this, 'save_admin_settings' ), 11, 3 );

    }

    /**
    * Load the plugin text domain for translation.
    *
    * With the introduction of plugins language packs in WordPress loading the textdomain is slightly more complex.
    *
    * We now have 3 steps:
    *
    * 1. Check for the language pack in the WordPress core directory
    * 2. Check for the translation file in the plugin's language directory
    * 3. Fallback to loading the textdomain the classic way
    *
    * @since   1.0.4
    * @return boolean True if the language file was loaded, false otherwise
    */
    public function load_plugin_textdomain() {

        $lang_dir       = WPASS_WOOCOMMERCE_ROOT . 'languages/';
        $lang_path      = WPASS_WOOCOMMERCE_PATH . 'languages/';
        $locale         = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', get_locale(), 'wpass_woocommerce' );
        $mofile         = "wpass_statuses-$locale.mo";
        $glotpress_file = WP_LANG_DIR . '/plugins/awesome-support-woocommerce/' . $mofile;

        // Look for the GlotPress language pack first of all
        if ( file_exists( $glotpress_file ) ) {
            $language = load_textdomain( 'wpass_woocommerce', $glotpress_file );
        } elseif ( file_exists( $lang_path . $mofile ) ) {
            $language = load_textdomain( 'wpass_woocommerce', $lang_path . $mofile );
        } else {
            $language = load_plugin_textdomain( 'wpass_woocommerce', false, $lang_dir );
        }

        return $language;

    }

}
```

and it another my plugin code

*/

```
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

/**
* Registering new post type for statuses
*
* @since 1.0.0
* @return void
*/

function wc_get_customer_orders() {

    // Get all customer orders
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
    ) );

    foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {
        $MyValueArray[] = $customer_order->ID;   
    }

    wpas_user_custom_fields($testArray);

    /* test array 
    $testArray = array("key1"=>"value1","key2"=>"value2","key3"=>"value3",);
    wpas_user_custom_fields($testArray);
    */
}

/**
 * Register all custom fields after the plugin is safely loaded.
*/
function wpas_user_custom_fields($MyValueArray) {
    if ( function_exists( 'wpas_add_custom_field' ) ) {
        wpas_add_custom_field( 'industry',
            array(
                'title' => __( 'Select your industry', 'wpas' ),
                'field_type' => 'select',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => $MyValueArray,
                )
        );
    }
}
```

my question is :

why when i use $testArray for wpas_user_custom_fields argument everything its ok ( value is show in back end and front end ) but when i use $MyValueArray for wpas_user_custom_fields argument, its just show in front end and not show in admin page?

Answer (score 0):

I found in [documentation](https://getawesomesupport.com/documentation/awesome-support/custom-fields/)

> #### Checkbox, Radio and Select-Only Parameters
>
> - **$options** (array): An array of options. The array must be or the form  `array( 'option_id' => 'Option Label' )`
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> wpas_add_custom_field( 'my_field_with_options', array( 
>        'title' => 'My Options', 
>        'options' => array( 
>               'option1' => 'First Option', 
>               'option2' => 'Second Option'), 
>        'order' => 1 ) );
> ```

You add the order IDs to array as values, not keys. Try to change array to `'order_ID' => 'order_title'`:

```
$MyValueArray = [];
foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) {
    $MyValueArray[$customer_order->ID] = $customer_order->post_title;
}
```

Comment: nothing happen!! the value of select is not show in admin panel. any solution???